# tkinter canvas image is not displayed in class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display an image in python using the tkinter canvas option. However, if I input it in a class, like below, it doesn't give an error but also doesn't show my image. The buttons are displayed correctly though. Also, if I take the code for generating this image out of the class it works correctly. I can't seem to find out what the problem is.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *

class Board(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):

        frame = Frame(parent)
        frame.pack()
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        frame2 = Frame(frame)
        frame2.pack()

        c=Canvas(frame2)
        c.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
        background=PhotoImage(file='Board.gif')
        c.create_image(100,100,image=background,anchor='nw')

        button = Button(frame, text="Next turn", command=self.next_turn)
        button.pack()

        button = Button(frame, text="Roll the dice", command=self.roll)
        button.pack()

        ....

root = Tk()
board = Board(root)
board.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: why are you doing both `import Tkinter as tk` AND `from Tkinter import *`?

Comment: My teacher told me to do that, to be sure everything got imported or something. I know it's not nessecary, but now there are some lines which have tk.'something' and if I just delete the tk. my program freaks out. You think that could be the problem?

Comment: That's probably because of the `tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)` and the `class Board(tk.Frame)`. You can change that to `Frame.__init__(self,parent)` and `class Board(Frame)`, which should work, though I'm not sure why you're directly calling an `__init__` method; I don't see what purpose that Frame serves either because you're not keeping reference to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to keep a reference to the PhotoImage. This is just and example (you can also use `self.background` instead of `c.background`):

```
    c = Canvas(frame2)
    c.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
    c.background = PhotoImage(file='Board.gif')
    c.create_image(100,100,image=c.background,anchor='nw')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the issue, really couldn't find it.

Comment: @user2438352 You're welcome, glad to be of help ;) Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Any idea why `Canvas.create_image()` increment the reference count of the `image=` it's passed so it will not destroyed when the function returns? Seems like it should according to usual Python's memory management rules.

Comment: Likewise, why does adding a reference to it in `c` work since `c` is also a local variable?

Comment: @martineau I think this may answer your question: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Suspicions confirmed. Thank you. Where I'm from we call things like that a bug and try to fix them asap, not just [document](http://web.archive.org/web/20070113034702/http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm) them.