# Tkinter not displaying image

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, image, python-3.3

I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import Pydeck
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

root = Tk()
name=""
def buttonclicked():
    name()
    picture()

def name():

    all_lists=[] #all lists
    text = inputfield.get()
    Pydeck.loadDatabase('DATABASE PATH')
    cardName = Pydeck.getCardsFromName(text)
    if not cardName == "":
            c = Pydeck.Card(cardName)
    tex.insert(END, c.name)
    level="\nLevel %s" % c.level + " " + c.attribute + " " + c.typestring 
    tex.insert(END, level)
    atk="\nAtk: %s" % c.attack
    tex.insert(END, atk)
    defe="\nDef: %s" % c.defense
    tex.insert(END, defe)
    typestring='\n%s' %c.typestring
    desc='\n%s' %c.description
    seperator='\n--------------------\n'
    tex.insert(END, typestring)
    tex.insert(END, desc)
    tex.insert(END,seperator)
    #--
    tex.see(END)             # Scroll if necessary
    return c.cardID


def picture():    
    text = inputfield.get()
    gifdir = "PICTURE FOLDERS PATH"
    Pydeck.loadDatabase('DATABASE PATH')
    cardName = Pydeck.getCardsFromName(text)
    if not cardName == "":
        c=Pydeck.Card(cardName)
    filename='{}.gif' .format(c.cardID)
    img = PhotoImage(file=gifdir+filename)
    can = Canvas(root)
    can.pack(fill=BOTH,side='top')
    can.config(width=img.width(), height=img.height())        
    can.create_image(2, 2, image=img, anchor=NW)

tex=Text(root)
tex.pack(side='right')
inputfield = Entry(root)
inputfield.pack(side='bottom')
but = Button(root,text="Enter Name", command = buttonclicked) #Calls name function
but.pack(side='bottom')
text = inputfield.get()

root.mainloop()
```

Ok, so in short the the program is in Tkinter for Python 3.3. It asks the user to input a name of a monster, it then searches for the monster in the database and returns the monster's attributes this is done in the `name` function. I want it to display a picture of the monster which is where I'm running into trouble. So the `picture` function takes one of the attributes specifically the `cardID` attribute and uses that as the name of the gif file. However it doesn't display the picture and I don't know why. Does anyone know why?

Comment: What _does_ it do...nothing or is an exception raised?

Comment: It searches a database for the monster, displays the monsters info and then shows the monsters image.

Comment: No, not what you want it to do, what it actually is doing that lead you to ask your question. BTW, what's `tex` in the `name()` function?

Comment: It's extending the frame of where the picture is supposed to be but it's not actually displaying a picture. And the `tex.insert` is to insert the variables inside the text box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get a stripped-down version of your code to display a .gif test image, I had to add a`global img`statement to the`picture()`function so the`PhotoImage`object that variable name refers to would not be destroyed when the function returns.

It seems strange that`Canvas.create_image()`doesn't increment the reference count of the`image`object it's passed...looks like it's a [documented bug](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm).

**Update:** For reasons I don't completely understand, adding a`can.img = img`right after the`can = Canvas(root)`in  the`picture()`function accomplishes the same thing in a better way than creating a global named`img`in my opinion.

Display from working version:

[image: a tk window showing test image being displayed]

Comment: Where exactly did you place the `global` at?

Comment: At the beginning of the `picture()` function. Note that making `img` a global isn't really a good solution. It would be better to make it an attribute of something longer-lived, instead of a local variable.

Comment: A common way to avoid this pitfall is illustrated in this [minimal tk application](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/minimal-app.html) where all the widgets created are made attributes of the derived `Application` class instance. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16846545/355230) to another question.