# image in canvas ( tkinter ) is not displayed when i use a button

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In my program, I want to show an image in a canvas which I created before    through a button command.

#### Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import Tk,Button,Canvas,PhotoImage
from PIL import Image, ImageTk



def dessiner ():

    

    # open the image 
    image = Image.open("img1.png")
    image = image.resize( (400,300), Image.ANTIALIAS) # resize the image to be show in the canvas
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    canvas.create_image(200, 175, image = img)
    
    

    return 0

mw = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(mw, \
width =400, height =650, \
bg="light yellow")
canvas.pack(side ="right")
button_plot = Button(mw, text = "dessiner", command = dessiner, width = 50, fg = "red")
button_plot.pack()
mw.mainloop()
```

Comment: My first guess would be that once `dessiner()` has been called, you lose the reference to `img`. In order for the image to be displayed correctly, you need to keep a reference to it. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846469/tkinter-canvas-image-is-not-displayed-in-class).

Comment: i don't think so, finally i find the solution by using the method ( 

      .show()     )

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution using the method .show()

```
 plt.show()
```

Comment: This makes no sense. The code in the question doesn't have a `plt`` object.

Comment: @BryanOakley  it works for me ! and i got a result

Comment: I'm sure there is lots of code that works for you. If it has nothing to do with the question being asked, it's a worthless answer. Stackoverflow isn't just for your benefit. Others may find your question when trying to solve their problems, and an answer that is a line of code that uses an object that is not part of the question is useless.

Comment: in my code, there is nothing related to the package "matplotlib" . i don't understand how it works in my code, i put it by hazard and it works finally.

Comment: it works for me, so it might works for an other !!!!

Comment: You are completely missing the point. It can't possibly work for another because they won't have a `plt` object. You simply _must_ have a `plt` object for this to work. Not only a  `plt` object, but one that has a `show` method. You can't fix code by just trying random statements. Your advice here is absolutely no different than if you had said "the solution is to call `xyz.foobar()`,

Comment: before using plt.show() 
i added :  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt !!