# Image does not display in tkinter Canvas

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to create a new class of Canvas that will be able to display and resize images. However The image does not display. I searched for similar questions and all the answers said to keep a reference of the PhotoImage in the class.( [This answer for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846469/tkinter-canvas-image-is-not-displayed-in-class)). I tried doing that in a number of ways and none worked. In this example I tried saving a reference in a dictionary. I also tried `self.tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)` which didn't work. And also tried using globals. I assume it has something to do with the garbage collector, but don't know how to solve. 
Please assist.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy as np
# a subclass of Canvas
class MyCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self,parent,**kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self,parent,**kwargs)
        self.tkimg = {}
        self.images = []
        self.image_on_canvas = []

    def my_create_image(self, *args, **kw):
        img = kw['image']
        self.images.append(img)
        self.tkimg[img] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        kw['image'] = self.tkimg[img]
        item = self.create_image(*args, **kw)
        self.image_on_canvas.append(item)



def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    myframe = tk.Frame(root)
    myframe.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)
    mycanvas1 = MyCanvas(myframe, width=850, height=400, bg="red", highlightthickness=0)

    mycanvas2 = MyCanvas(myframe, width=850, height=400, bg="green", highlightthickness=0)
    mycanvas1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)
    mycanvas2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

    # add some widgets to the canvas

    mycanvas2.create_line(0, 100, 200, 0, fill="red", dash=(4, 4))
    mycanvas2.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")
    arr1 = np.random.random([256,256])*255
    img1 = Image.fromarray(arr1)
    mycanvas1.my_create_image(0, 0, image=img1, anchor=tk.NW)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Based on the code posted, you never create an instance of `MyCanvas`. Is that a typo? Did you not run the code you posted before posting?

Comment: Yes, Thanks, I fixed it. I ran the code but then made a few minor changes to try and make it more compact

Comment: Have tried writing your code using an existing image, to verify whether the problem is "the image won't display" or if it's "the image isn't being generated correctly"? How do you know it's a tkinter problem rather than a `Image.fromarray` problem?

Comment: Yes. When I move the 'ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)' out of the function and pass it directly instead for callint ImageTk.PhotoImage inside 'my_create_image' then it displays properly. I also tried displaying the image with matplotlib and PIL and both worked